# Use the given data to find an approximation for $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, approximation

I have the following question in the book:

[image]

But I do not know how to answer it, the only piece of information that my professor said is that a function differentiable means that it can be approximated by linear function, could anyone explain for me how to answer this question please?

**EDIT:**

**The question contains a mistake as the vector x is 3 dimensional not 2.**

Comment: Sorry I could not understand what you have written @Mattos could you provide more details ..... do you mean the jacobian at the given point by your second term?

Comment: yes I have but I do not know how to apply it in the above problem @Mattos

Comment: Does not the given  $D f(3,-1)$ should be  $D^2 f(3,-1)$? @Mattos

Comment: yes $x _{0}= (3, -1)$ and $x = (3,1,-0.8)$ but then what .... how can I find the approximation?

Comment: @Mattos please see my previous comment

Comment: this approximation formula you given to me is for a function in one variable but our function is in three variables and how willI calculate the error in approximation?@Mattos

Comment: I understand what you mean now but I am stucked in calculation $D^2 f(3,-1)$ .... I know that my function is from $\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ ..... am I correct? @Mattos

Comment: why our x is 3 dimensional ?@Mattos?

Comment: I got the answer (22/3,10) am I correct?@Mattos